# Kafka setup with docker using kafka-rb for clients

Tags: ruby, docker, boot2docker, apache-kafka

I am completely new to Kafka and I have trouble getting it right.

I have following setup with "wurstmeister/kafka-docker" for docker using docker-compose:

```
zookeeper:
 image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
 ports: 
   - "2181:2181"
kafka:
 image: wurstmeister/kafka
 ports:
   - "9092:9092"
 links: 
   - zookeeper:zk
 environment:
   KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.59.103
   # KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPCIS_ENABLE: 'true'
   KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "events:1:1"
 volumes:
   - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

For a producer and consumer I am using ruby gem "kafka-rb".

Producer:

```
require 'kafka'
producer = Kafka::Producer.new({
    host: "192.168.59.103",
    port: 9092,
    topic: "events"
})

1000000.times do |i|
    message = Kafka::Message.new("Message #{i}")
    producer.push(message)
end
```

Consumer:

require 'kafka'

```
consumer = Kafka::Consumer.new({
    host: "192.168.59.103",
    port: 9092,
    topic: "events"
})

consumer.loop do |messages|
    puts "Received"
    puts messages
end
```

But I am still getting refused connections or error:

```
[2015-07-15 09:50:49,769] ERROR Closing socket for /192.168.59.3 because of error (kafka.network.Processor)
kafka_1     | java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
kafka_1     |   at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.get(HeapByteBuffer.java:145)
kafka_1     |   at java.nio.ByteBuffer.get(ByteBuffer.java:692)
kafka_1     |   at kafka.api.ApiUtils$.readShortString(ApiUtils.scala:38)
kafka_1     |   at kafka.api.LeaderAndIsrRequest$.readFrom(LeaderAndIsrRequest.scala:108)
kafka_1     |   at kafka.api.RequestKeys$$anonfun$5.apply(RequestKeys.scala:43)
kafka_1     |   at kafka.api.RequestKeys$$anonfun$5.apply(RequestKeys.scala:43)
kafka_1     |   at kafka.network.RequestChannel$Request.<init>(RequestChannel.scala:50)
kafka_1     |   at kafka.network.Processor.read(SocketServer.scala:450)
kafka_1     |   at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:340)
kafka_1     |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

Is there something fundamentally wrong with the setup? Thank you

Comment: Should your consumer also be connecting to Zookeeper, not Kafka?

Comment: Actually I need to connect to Zookeeper, but I was using wrong library. As this one doesn't really take care of a Zookeeper in the middle, but this one does: https://github.com/joekiller/jruby-kafka

Answer (score 0):

When does this error happened, running `wurstmeister/zookeeper` image or when u try to produce or consume message.

why it report `Closing socket for /192.168.59.3`, should it be `192.168.59.103`, can u try to ping or telnet the kafka server in the places where u run the producer and consumer to see whether you can connect to it or not.